# Using PSR4-Autoloading via Composer vs spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

We're building a new Slim application and we want to use PSR4-Autoloading with namespaces in our code.

We found two ways to do that, via Composer i.e.:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Controller\\": "app/controllers",
        "App\\Middleware\\": "app/middleware",
        "App\\Model\\": "app/models"     
    }
},
```

Or via `spl_autoload_register` i.e.:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {

  $filename = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class_name) . '.php';
  require $filename;

});
```

What determines which method we should go with?

Comment: Using composer is going to be way more robust, and allow you to import packages.

Comment: If you are not using `composer`, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @localheinz we're using composer to maintain our vendor libraries

Comment: Then do yourself a favor and just use `composer`'s autoloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version with `spl_autoload_register` could be faster, because it is directly suited to you. But because you are using Composer for autoloading your depenendecies, your version will be likely be as fast or even slower than the Composer implementation.

There is a principle called *Don't repeat yourself* so why making something *new*, when the people from Composer already thought about it and implemented it.

That being said, Composer also uses `spl_autoload_register` internally

Conclusion: Use the Composer psr-4 autoload, its probably more robust than your implementation, and equally as fast performance-wise.